# R package for Kalman filtering of data

Tags: r

Criteria:

- numerical stability
- speed
- benign scaling properties when the number of dimensions in the state space goes up
- support for time-varying matrices and support for irregularly-spaced observations
- ease of setup (measured by lines of code)

For answerers' sake here's a [paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v39/i02/paper) doing part of the comparison (2011). It mentions dse, sspir, dlm, FKF, KFAS packages, as well as some others. Personal opinions are of much interest.